# SQL Slightly complicated query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Question: Write a query to find academics that are authors and that have only ever coauthored papers with authors from institutes in the same state as their own. List their academic number, title and last name.

I've been working on this question for some time and I haven't been able to think of a proper query.

My schema for the database (tables) I need to use:

```
ACADEMIC(ACNUM, DEPTNUM, FAMNAME, TITLE)
DEPARTMENT(DEPTNUM, STATE)
AUTHOR(PANUM, ACNUM)
```

There are multiple ACNUM's (Account number) for 1 PANUM (Page number) inside the Author table.

I tried planning it and all I could think of was something along the lines of this:

Need to loop through Author table,

```
SELECT PANUM
FROM AUTHOR A
```

Then need to find all authors of that paper:

```
SELECT ACNUM
FROM AUTHOR B
WHERE PANUM = A.PANUM;
```

Then need to intersect all states:

```
SELECT DEPTNUM, TITLE, FAMNAME, UPPER(STATE)
FROM ACADEMIC C, DEPARTMENT D
WHERE C.ACNUM = B.ACNUM AND D.DEPTNUM = C.DEPTNUM;
```

Could you guys give me some assistance on how I could do something like this? I appreciate any help.

EDIT: Some more information

I haven't actually figured out a desired result as theres hundreds of rows of data. Essentially, I have to query the database by: Selecting page number from Author table, then finding all Account Number's that the Author table has for that page number, then using all these account numbers I need to make sure they are all in the same state. E.g. Account 100 and 101 worked on page number 300 together and both are in state VIC, thus I would list the academics information (famname, title and acnum)

Comment: Please provide (add as  text to your question) your test data and the desired result.

Comment: I think we can solve this without test data, but yes that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query out a table joining the `ACADEMIC`, `DEPARTMENT`, and `AUTHOR` tables, and then *self-join* that table by paper, restricting on state, to obtain the result you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.FAMNAME, DISTINCT t1.TITLE FROM
(ACADEMIC a1 INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d1 ON a1.DEPTNUM = d1.DEPTNUM
INNER JOIN AUTHOR auth1 ON a1.ACNUM = auth1.ACNUM) t1
INNER JOIN
(ACADEMIC a2 INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d2 ON a2.DEPTNUM = d2.DEPTNUM
INNER JOIN AUTHOR auth2 ON a2.ACNUM = auth2.ACNUM) t2
GROUP BY t1.PANUM
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.STATE) = 1;
```

Comment: The query above works, however doesn't produce the expected results. My list needs to consist of authors that co-authored the book where ALL authors are from the same state. I've included an image that shows PANUM #7 is returned even though there is another author from another state. https://imgur.com/KcrI1zT.png

Comment: @JohnnyDoey I updated my query to `GROUP BY` the paper, and then retain only records where _all_ the author states are the same.